# htaccess redirect problems

Tags: apache-httpd, htaccess

In my `var/www/html/` folder there are 2 Angular applications.

One is search and the other one login.
There is no `index.html` file in `/var/www/html/` only 2 folders which contains each a `index.html` file.

What I want to do is when a user goes to  http://mydomain.de/
The user will be redirected to the folder `/var/www/html/search/`
Also in all other cases: e.g. http://mydomaim.de/notexisting

In the Search page there is a link to `http://login/`, folder `/var/www/html/login/`

So when the user goes to `http://mydomain.de/login`, it should redirect to this folder.

My tries so far:
    RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
#RewriteRule login$ /login/index.html$1 [N]
#RewriteRule ^search*/$ /search/index.html$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/search/
RewriteRule (.*) /search/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/login/
RewriteRule (.login*) /login/$1
```

Thank you and Kind Regards,

PS: When I only use this search page is working but not the login page.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/search/
RewriteRule (.*) /search/$1
```

Comment: “What I want to do is when a user goes to …  The user will be directed to … Also in all other cases.” — This is logical the same as “always direct user to …”. I am sure this is not what you meant, and it is central to you question, can you edit to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple if you only want to exclude `/login/` from your `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/search/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/login/
RewriteRule (.*) /search/$1 [R,L]
```

I added the flags `[R,L]` for a 302 redirect and to stop processing of any further rules in your `.htaccess` file.
You can remove the `R` if you don't want redirection to take place.

Flags:

- [R|redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r)
- [L|last](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)